# regex golang last match of a pattern inside curly braces

Tags: regex, go

I have the following string, and I want to match the contents of the last curly brace (inclusive), i.e. the output should be `{ahhh}`.

```
abc {popo}/popo/{ahhh}
```

Golang does not support negative lookahead, and I have tried the following patterns but it has not worked

```
{.+?}$
```

```
{.+?}([^/])
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I guess I could, I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way of obtaining the last match

Comment: Try: `.*({[^}]*})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match from an opening till closing curly at the end of the string:

```
\{[^{}]*}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJqm1X/1)

Or you could match the whole line, and then capture the last occurrence of the curly's followed by matching any char except `/` till the end of the string.

```
.*(\{[^{}]*})[^/]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SO7ogN/1)